# API authentication in VBA

Tags: vba, authentication

I'm trying to authentication using VBA with FTX API, which requires a signature as follow (taken from https://docs.ftx.com/?python#authentication). They have this example in Python:

```
signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()
signature = hmac.new('YOUR_API_SECRET'.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()
```

So I understand that the `signature_payload` and `apisecret` need to be encoded, then the `signature_payload`is hashed with hmac using `apisecret` as key, then convert to hex. How can I do these steps in VBA? I dont know much other than some basic VBA so glad if someone could help

Comment: That website provides a C# example. VBA is much more related to C# than python, and some of the objects used can even be used within VBA. `Httprequest` can be used via `CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")` and the `.Headers.Add` is written `.setRequestHeader`

Comment: I am familiar with creating http request, I was just asking about generating the signature hex to authenticate which I couldn't find any built-in function to do. I finally found https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba which contains the necessary function